# Equal generator sets

Tags: group-theory

Apparently $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h, r_v \rangle $ is equal to $ \langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h,r_hr_v \rangle $ where  each of these groups is described by a set of generators with $t_L$ representing a translation by a distance L,  $t_{L/2}r_h$ is a glide reflection, $r_v$ is vertical reflection and $r_hr_v$ is a rotation, but I'm having a hard time seeing how these two are equal.

I tried some things... but apparently $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h, r_v \rangle $ is also equal to $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h,t_{L/2}r_v,r_hr_v \rangle$ which I then see how $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h, r_v \rangle $ is equal to $ \langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h,r_hr_v \rangle$ because the composition of $ t_{L/2}r_h$ and $r_hr_v$ is $t_{L/2}r_v$. But I don't understand how to get $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h,t_{L/2}r_v,r_hr_v \rangle$.

Can someone please help me understand/demonstrate how $\langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h, r_v \rangle $ is equal to $ \langle t_L,t_{L/2}r_h,r_hr_v \rangle $

Comment: Is $L$ a fixed constant, or do your group generators include $t_L$ for all $L$? If $L$ is a fixed constant, then I don't believe that the two groups are equal, although they are isomorphic.